# Selecting a minimum sum of columns for a group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, database-design

I am having difficulty finding a simple solution to this problem.

You can assume `UNIQUE KEY (A, B, C, D, E)`.

[image: Data Sample]

I am trying to `SELECT` all rows from the above table such that for every unique group of `C, D, E`, I want the `A, B` such that `A + B <=` all other `A + B` combinations for that particular group of `C, D, E`.

So performing the `SELECT` on the above data should yield (in the case of a tie, pick the first one):

[image]

If I were to `GROUP BY C, D, E`, the columns `A, B` are chosen arbitrarily (technically first `A, B` encountered by database internally).

If this were *relational algebra*, I'd cross join the relation with itself, select where `C, D, E` are equal across 'both' relations and where `A + B` from one copy of the relation is greater than `A + B` of the other copy and then subtract the result from the original relation.

I figure though, that there's a simpler way of doing this in `MySQL`. The table may have thousands of groups of `C, D, E`, each group containing 5 to 10 `A, B`. I don't believe a `CROSS JOIN` would be very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this could be to select the minimum for every combination of `c`, `d`, `e` and then join it with a query on the table:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM   mytable t
JOIN   (SELECT   c, d, e, MIN(a + b) AS min_ab
        FROM     mytable
        GROUP BY c, d, e) s ON t.c = s.c AND
                               t.d = s.d AND
                               t.e = s.e AND
                               t.a + t.b = s.min_ab
```

Comment: Even though it is not standard SQL, the OP will probably want to `GROUP BY c, d, e` in the outer query as well to eliminate ties. However, it is worth noting, that the desired "in the case of a tie, pick the first one" decision is not (pedantically speaking) possible with this table structure, since table's don't have inherent "first" rows; the row the a and b values not included in the GROUP BY come from is not defined... while I would bet against it, it would even be theoretically possible for them to come from separate rows.

Comment: @Uueerdo There'd be a "first one" if there was an `ORDER BY`, right? Either way, the only reason I mentioned "pick the first" was to remove ambiguity and ensure consistency. Otherwise, as long as the sums of the values are a minimum, the data serves its purpose.

Comment: @noahnu Since `ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`, I am doubtful that would help. Perhaps if `mytable t` above were converted into something like `(SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY c, d, e, a, b) AS t` you could provide some consistency. Depending on what you are using it for I wouldn't worry too much; I would generally expect the results to be consistent from minute to minute as long as a lot of DELETE and INSERT statements are not occurring between executions of this query.